# Show message if all Li are hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup, jquery-filter

What i want is that if on `keyup()` if all the li are hidden then show a specfic div.I Following is my Jquery Code. Currently what is happening is that div is displayed when ever it 1st meets its success scenario, my fiddle will explain the scenario more.

```
 var showMessage = false;
    function filter(element) {
        var value = $(element).val();
        $(".dropd > li").each(function () {
            if ($(this).text().indexOf(value) > -1) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                showMessage = true;
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
        if (showMessage == true) {
            alert(showMessage + '111');
            $('.dropd').find('#not_matches').hide();
        }
    }
 $('#txt_colors').keyup(function () {
        filter(this);
    });
```

Following is my HTML

```
<div id="dd2" class="wrapper-dropdown-2" tabindex="1">
   <div class="selected" style="margin-right:30px;"> select Color</div>
      <ul class="dropd"> <input id="txt_colors" type="text"/>
         <div id="not_matches" name="not_matches" style="display: none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;No Matching Color </div>
           <li onclick="search_ral_pantone('000000')" value="000000" style="border-right-color:#000000"><a>Black</a></li>
            <li onclick="search_ral_pantone('0000FF')" value="0000FF" style="border-right-color:#0000FF"><a>Blue</a></li>
            <li onclick="search_ral_pantone('808080')" value="000000" style="border-right-color:#808080"><a>Gray</a></li>
            <li onclick="search_ral_pantone('00FF00')" value="00FF00" style="border-right-color:#00FF00"><a>Green</a></li>
            <li onclick="search_ral_pantone('800000')" value="800000" style="border-right-color:#800000"><a>Maroon</a></li>
            <li onclick="search_ral_pantone('800080')" value="800080" style="border-right-color:#800080"><a>Purple</a></li>
            <li onclick="search_ral_pantone('FF0000')" value="FF0000" style="border-right-color:#FF0000"><a>Red</a></li>
            <li onclick="search_ral_pantone('C0C0C0')" value="C0C0C0" style="border-right-color:#C0C0C0"><a>Silver</a></li>
            <li onclick="search_ral_pantone('FFFFFF')" value="FFFFFF" style="border-right-color:#FFFFFF"><a>White</a></li>
            <li onclick="search_ral_pantone('FFFF00')" value="FFFF00" style="border-right-color:#FFFF00"><a>Yellow</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
```

**Fiddle:**http://jsfiddle.net/13y6b7jj/1/ (just to give idea as to what is actually happening)

Comment: you are showing that message when `showMessage=false` ?? I think when the text doesn't matched with any of the `li` texts then you need to display that message but you are hiding ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if any li is visible by this code:

```
$(".dropd li:visible").length
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/13y6b7jj/9/)

Answer (score 1):

now i see the problem. You could do something like:

```
if ($(".dropd > li:visible").length === 0)
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/13y6b7jj/7/)

Comment: Check your fiddle, for test type **1** and then see what the out put is

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

If the selector passed in `.is` match atleast 1 element in the stack, it will return true. You just have to invert the value returned :

```
function filter(element) {
    var value = $(element).val();
    var $li = $(".dropd > li").each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().indexOf(value) > -1) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }

        // Alternative code here :
        // $(this).toggle($(this).text().indexOf(value) > -1);
    });
    if (! $li.is(':visible')) {
        alert(showMessage + '111');
        $('.dropd').find('#not_matches').hide();
    }
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/13y6b7jj/8/)

Answer (score 0):

you should use this:

```js
function filter(element) {
            var value = $(element).val();
            var count = 0;
            $(".dropd > li").each(function () {
                if ($(this).text().indexOf(value) > -1) {
                    $(this).show();
                    count++;
                } else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
            if (count != 0) 
            {
                $('.dropd').find('#not_matches').hide();
            }
            else{
                $('.dropd').find('#not_matches').show();
            }
        }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/13y6b7jj/5/)

Answer (score 0):

you just need to modify your code . You are hiding the message where you need to show and vice-versa

```
if (showMessage) {
       $('.dropd').find('#not_matches').show();
   } else {
            $('.dropd').find('#not_matches').hide();
          }
```